# Javascript array.length of elements doesn't work with less than 2 elements?

Tags: javascript, checkbox

Here's a simple little javascript function that makes an array of all checkboxes (video) in my form (myform), and builts another array of the checkboxes that are checked.  It works great unless there's only 1 checkbox in the form. In that case boxes is undefined.  Shouldn't this work with document.myform.video.length is 1?

```
function toggle(main) {
    boxes = document.myform.video.length;
    alert(boxes);
    var videos = [];
    for (i=0; i<boxes; i++) {
            document.myform.video[i].checked = main.checked;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

no, if there is only one element by that name, the DOM would show it as the element not an array.

Comment: Well, heck, that makes it a little more complicated.. having to check to see if it's an element or an array. I'm not sure how I'd do that.

Comment: @Adam, its kind of a pain to determine if something is an array, but the best approach i have found is [crockfords approach](https://gist.github.com/1133122).

Comment: in curcumstances such as this one using the getElementsByTagName() method instead of the properties of the document object normally works for me.  Just filter your results to only include type="checkbox" and the returned results will be Array-like regardless whether there's one or more results :)

Comment: I solved the issue by testing document.myform.video.length and pushing document.myform.video into a new array, or copy in document.myform.video[] into it, depending on the length.